# Copying the contents from one pointer to another

Tags: c++, pointers

I have 2 class:

```
    class Request
    {
      KeyValuePair* dimension;
    };

    class Response
    {
      KeyValuePair* dimension;
    };

    class KeyValuePair
    {
        public:
        hash_map<string, string> hmap;
    };
```

in one of the method, I want to populate the `Response.dimension` with `Request.dimension` but I want the `Request.dimension` pointing to a different address from `Response.dimension`?

I don't want any change  `Response.dimension` which also affect `Request.dimension`.

Is there a way to do that?

```
void Transformation::applyTransformations(const Request& req, Response& res)
{
   res.dimension = req.dimension; // WRONG. Pointing the same address.
}
```

Comment: How is `KeyValuePair` defined ? Does it have a suitable (copy) constructor ?

Comment: If you have the copy constructor properly defined, you can do `res.dimension = new KeyValuePair(req.dimension);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, of course:

```
*(res.dimension) = *(req.dimension);
```

Note that if `KeyValuePair` is not a POD type, you should define the assignment operator (`operator =`), as it will get called during the assignment. If you don't, the compiler-generated one will be called.

You should also check if `res.dimension` is properly allocated, if not, use the copy constructor:

```
if ( res.dimension )
   *(res.dimension) = *(req.dimension);
else
   res.dimension = new KeyValuePair(*(req.dimension));
```

Comment: This assumes that storage has been allocated for `*(res.dimension)`, which may not be the case

Comment: sorry. what is POD? I have updated to put my KeyValuePair in the question. If let say KeyValuePair is not a POD, can you show me a tutorial to define the assignment operator? Thanks!

Comment: @Rudy plain old data. Also, I'm sure you could easily find a tutorial if you google.

Answer (score 1):

You can overload the `=`operator of your `Response` class to perform a deep copy of the  `request.dimension`, this will make your `Response.dimension` have same value as that of `Request.dimension` and yet will be independent of any changes to `Request.dimension`.

Comment: Of course, he'll have to remember to dereference the pointers when assigning.

Answer (score 0):

[Copy constructor](http://www.fredosaurus.com/notes-cpp/oop-condestructors/copyconstructors.html)

[More on C++ copy constructors](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%2B%2B+copy+constructor&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aes-ES%3aofficial&client=firefox-a)

Comment: This is really not a useful answer. There should *almost always* be more than just a link.

Comment: [Plenty of them](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%2B%2B+copy+constructor&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:es-ES:official&client=firefox-a)

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate new memory. Also you need to have copy constructor(or use the default one if appropriate).

`res.dimension = new KeyValuePair(req.dimension);`

Also you will have to handle the memory i.e. define a copy constructor, copy operator, empty constructor and destructor.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a '[copy on write](http://ootips.org/yonat/4dev/cow_ptr.h)' pointer, to avoid unneeded overhead.